# Android Tcp Client check connection to the Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, client

Hi i have a Tcp client and i want to check if he is connected to the server and i dont mean to check if he was connected with socket.isConnected() or socket.isBound() i mean that i want to know if the socket is connected right now and i couldnt find a way to do it because when the server disconnect he dosnt send anything to the client

here is my code:

```
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient() {
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;
    try {
        //connecting
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        sss = socket;


        try {
            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            //receive the message that the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            HelloService.firstTouch();


            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class to inform main activity that a message has received
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {

            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: If @EJP's answer doesn't work for you (hmmm though), try pinging the server or use `isReachable()`.

Comment: tried it but it kept returning false anything else? its very important please someone ?

Comment: Isn't `isReachable()` returning `false` meaning server disconnected?

Comment: yea but it always returns false even when the server is not disconnected

Answer (score 0):

When the server disconnects, `readLine()` returns null, which you need to check for, and break out of the read loop and close the connection if you get it. Your present checking is only sufficient to avoid an NPE.

Comment: the thing is that it dos'nt return anything i have already tried it